# Print a comma every two fields in bash

Tags: bash, loops, printing, awk

For example I have a list of names (first and last):

```
Tom Smith Mary Brown Harry Anderson Sally Hall
```

I would like to output this as:

```
Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson, Sally Hall
```

Bonus points if I/You can throw in an ***'and'*** after the "last" comma.

Now I know I could throw it into a for loop and print and iterate and check if is if three fields from the end to the end, but I thought there must be an easier way with awk or another command.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In case you weren't aware, the reason that you have attracted so many downvotes is that you have shown no attempt made to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: My attempt would have been messy.  I did mention I would have just thrown it into a for loop, printed out two at a time and iterate.  I knew this was messy and why I came to the forum.  But ya I was wondering.

Comment: Maybe it would have been messy but it is always better to show your attempt at solving a problem rather than simply posting the question. In future, you should do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `sed` for this:

```
$ sed -r 's/(\w* \w*) /\1, /g' <<< "Tom Smith Mary Brown Harry Anderson Sally Hall"
Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson, Sally Hall
```

This selects a group of two space separated words and prints it back together with a comma.

To print an `and` instead of the last comma, do catch everything before last comma and print it back with the text `and` instead:

```
$ sed -r -e 's/(\w* \w*) /\1, /g' -e 's/, ([^,]*)$/ and \1/' <<< "Tom Smith Mary Brown Harry Anderson Sally Hall" 
Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson and Sally Hall
```

Comment: I went with you last one.  It takes into account a single name combination, in addition to multiple name combinations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<(NF-2);i+=2) printf "%s %s, ", $i, $(i+1); print "and", $(NF-1), $NF}' file
Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson, and Sally Hall
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought i'd add another awk

```
awk '{while(++i<NF-2)printf "%s",$i (i%2?FS:", ");print $i" and "$++i,$NF}'

Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson and Sally Hall
```

If you want the comma before the and

```
awk '{while(++i<NF-1)printf "%s",$i (i%2?FS:", ");print "and "$i,$NF}'
Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson,and Sally Hall
```

No and

```
 awk '{while(++i<NF)printf "%s",$i (i%2?FS:", ");print $NF}'
 Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson, Sally Hall
```

Finally a mix of mine and anubhavas

```
 awk '{while((i+=2)<NF-1)$i=$i","}--i&&$i="and "$i'
```

Comment: I modified it a little but it is good to see another perspective.  Thanks.

     awk '{while(++i<NF-2)printf "%s",$i (i%2?FS:", ");print $i", and "$++i,$NF}'

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
s='Tom Smith Mary Brown Harry Anderson Sally Hall'
awk '{for (i=2; i<NF-1; i+=2) $i = $i ","; $(NF-1)="and " $(NF-1)} 1' <<< "$s"
Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson, and Sally Hall
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
echo "Tom Smith Mary Brown Harry Anderson Sally Hall
1 2 3 4" | awk '{for (i=1;i<NF-2;i+=2){printf("%s %s, ", $i, $(i+1)) };print "and "$(NF-1), $NF;}'

Tom Smith, Mary Brown, Harry Anderson, and Sally Hall
1 2, and 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather easy one, using `set`:

```
set -- Tom Smith Mary Brown Harry Anderson Sally Hall
while (($#)); do
    printf '%s %s' "$1" "$2"
    shift 2 || shift
    if (($#>2)); then printf ', '; elif (($#)); then printf ' and '; fi
done
printf '\n'
```

So that you can put all this in a nice function:

```
sep_them() {
    while (($#)); do
        printf '%s %s' "$1" "$2"
        shift 2 || shift
        if (($#>2)); then printf ', '; elif (($#)); then printf ' and '; fi
    done
    printf '\n'
}
```

and use it:

```
gniourf$ sep_them one
one 
gniourf$ sep_them one two
one two
gniourf$ sep_them one two three
one two and three 
gniourf$ sep_them one two three four
one two and three four
gniourf$ sep_them one two three four five
one two, three four and five 
gniourf$ sep_them one two three four five six
one two, three four and five six
gniourf$ sep_them one two three four five six seven
one two, three four, five six and seven 
gniourf$ sep_them one two three four five six seven eight
one two, three four, five six and seven eight
gniourf$ sep_them one two three four five six seven "eight with a space"
one two, three four, five six and seven eight with a space
```